# GLSurfaceView floating on top of the dashboard layout

Tags: android, opengl-es, surfaceview, glsurfaceview

Im creating a transparent sub-glsurfaceview on a layout (making zorderontop(true)) and placing it in a scrollview.

In my parent viewgroup which is a relative layout, at the top im having a dashboard and below that the scrollview containg the glsurfaceview.

When Im scrolling the view **the surfaceview moves on the top of the dashboard** but I want my glsurfaceview go below that dashboard.

If I make my zorderontop(false) the background is not transparent. how to achieve it?

please someone help me.

Thanks a lot in advance.